# $\{ b_i + v \}$ is a basis for $V$ if $v = \sum \alpha_i b_i$ such that $\sum \alpha_i \neq -1$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I've tested this with many examples and they seem to work. For $\sum \alpha_i = -1$, I've come up with a counterexample to a possible generalization.

My proof is as follows:

Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $\mathcal{B}$. Let $v \in V$ be a vector such that $\sum \alpha_i \neq -1$, that is, the sum of all its coefficients in a linear combination with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ is not $-1$. Then the set $\mathcal{B}_v$, defined as $\mathcal{B}_v =\{ b_i + v \mid b_i \in \mathcal{B} \}$ is a basis for $V$.

First, we prove that $\mathcal{B}_v$ is linearly independent. For that, suppose
\begin{equation}
\sum a_i b_{v_i} = 0, b_{v_i} \in \mathcal{B}_v \; .
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
0 = \sum a_i b_{v_i} = \sum a_i (b_i + v) = \sum a_i b_i + \left( \sum a_i \right) v
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum a_i b_i + \left( \sum a_i \right) v = \sum a_i b_i + \left( \sum a_i \right) \left( \sum \alpha_i b_i \right) = \sum \left( a_i + \alpha_i \sum a_i \right) b_i
\end{equation}
Linear independence in $\mathcal{B}$ implies $ a_i + \alpha_i \sum a_j  = 0$ for all $i$. Adding the equalities for all $i$, we have
\begin{equation}
\sum a_i + \left( \sum \alpha_i \right) \left( \sum a_i \right) = \left( \sum \alpha_i + 1 \right) \left( \sum a_i \right) = 0
\end{equation}
Since $\sum \alpha_i \neq -1$, the equality implies $\sum a_i = 0$ and so for each individual equality we have $ a_i + \alpha_i (0) = 0 \implies a_i = 0$ for all $i$. Hence, $\mathcal{B}_v$ is linearly independent.

Now, we prove $\mathcal{B}_v$ spans $V$. We take the coefficients $\alpha_i$ of $v$ and make a linear combination, but using the set $\mathcal{B}_v$:
\begin{equation}
\sum \alpha_i b_{v_i} = \sum \alpha_i b_i + \left( \sum \alpha_i \right) v = \left( \sum \alpha_i + 1 \right) v \; .
\end{equation}
Since $\sum \alpha_i \neq -1$, we have
\begin{equation}
\left( \sum \alpha_i + 1 \right)^{-1} \left( \sum \alpha_i b_{v_i} \right) = v \; .
\end{equation}
For any $b_{v_i} \in \mathcal{B}_v$, we have
\begin{equation}
b_{v_i} - \left( \sum \alpha_i + 1 \right)^{-1} \left( \sum \alpha_i b_{v_i} \right) = b_{v_i} - v = b_i \; ,
\end{equation}
so every element of the original basis is in the span of $\mathcal{B}_v$, implying it spans all $V$.

---

This concludes the proof, but I'd also like to ask if my solution to an exercise in which I applied this result could also be verified (I apologize for the lengthy question but creating a separate one would be confusing without the explanation of my result).

The exercise is the following:

> b) Prove that if a subspace S of $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains a strongly positive vector [ $v = (a_1, ..., a_n)$ where $a_i > 0$ ], then $S$ has a basis of strongly positive vectors.

My solution:
Let $v$ the strongly positive vector, and $\mathcal{C}$ a basis for $S$. Since $v \in S$, $\lambda v \in S$. We find the vector in $\mathcal{C}$ with the smallest coordinate of all, $\epsilon_c$. We also take the smallest coordinate of $v$, $\epsilon_v$. First, we multiply $v$ by $\epsilon_v^{-1}$, so that the smallest coordinate of v is $1$. Then we multiply $v$ again by $\vert \epsilon_c \vert + 1$, so that the smallest coordinate in $v$ suffices to make $\epsilon_c$ positive in an eventual sum of vectors, in the worst case possible. The final step is optional, and must be applied only if the sum of coefficients of $v$ with respect to $\mathcal{C}$ is $-1$. If so, we multiply $v$ by $\lambda > 1$, which does not make $v$ smaller and changes the sum of coeffients to a different value. Now, we create a set $\mathcal{C}_v =\{ c_i + v \mid c_i \in \mathcal{C} \}$, and with the above result we have that $\mathcal{C}_v$ is a basis for $S$, and entirely strongly positive, since $v$ can make the smallest coordinate greater than $0$ in the summations that occur.

---

Are there any mistakes in the steps of my proof? What about the exercise? Even if the result is true, is my solution correct?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can shorten your first proof. You only need to show the set spans $V$. It will automatically be a basis since it contains the same number of vectors as the basis.

Comment: The exercise question has been asked before. Here's a link to the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/424733/55622